# Batch script to fetch and play specific video file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am having trouble with creating a batch file which then can be mapped to a keyboard shortcut, The basic's of the script is it asks for the season, episode and shot and finds it via that input in the directory however I having trouble with the fact that some folders have specific names at the end and I cant understand how to go about creating wild cards.

```
@echo off 
        
set /p Series=Series: 
set /p Episode=Episode: 
set Series=00%Series% 
set Episode=00000%Episode% 
set Episode=%Episode:~-3%
         
rem open up review
         
set Path="P:\projectName\06_review\series_%Series%\sr%Series%_ep_%Episode%"
        
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /A:-D /B /O:-D /S %Path%') do set NEW=%%a&& goto:n  
:n 
start %NEW%
```

So far this is doing well grabbing the latest file but once it needs to grab a folder that has more characters after `\sr%Series%_ep_%Episode%` it fails, but what is the best way to create wild cards for any possible string after the matching input?

Comment: First of all, don't mess with the `%path%` variable. It's a system variable that tells `cmd` where to find its executables. Choose another name.

Comment: There are wrong line-breaks at the end of your scripts – please review your post and correct it…

Comment: I have found it is generally the best practice to not put QUOTATION MARK characters into a variable value. Instead of `set Path="P:\projectName\06_review\series_%Series%\sr%Series%_ep_%Episode%"` I would use `SET "PAT=P:\projectName\06_review\series_%Series%\sr%Series%_ep_%Episode%"`. Then, use QUOTATION MARK characters when the variable is used, such as `dir /A:-D /B /O:-D /S "%PAT%"`. As Stephen said, do not mess with the PATH variable in any frivolous way.

Comment: @lit Would you be able to give me some more detail? I am quite fresh to batch and I am still trying to understand how this works all works, thanks! :)